How can I interrupt/kill a shell command quickly?
Sometimes in a shell session (i.e. with M-x shell) a command will output a whole ton of output very quickly and I'll want to stop it with C-c C-c. In a normal terminal, this works just fine, but with emacs it can take ages to be responsive, so it grinds emacs to a halt and maybe I just have to wait for the command to finish, which can take ages and occasionally I'll just forcibly quit and restart through the OS. It gets worse with more/faster output.
Is there a better way to interrupt runaway commands?

IME, C-c C-c in a *shell* buffer works just as well as doing C-c on a teminal. What version of Emacs are you using? What OS? Are there particular long-running commands that cause the problem or is is all such commands?

The question needs more specific info, such as a recipe to repro (starting from emacs -Q.
